# Best way to load a matlab 3D cell in python

Tags: python, matlab

I have a 3D cell containing matrices in matlab and I want to load it in python in some convenient way. Each cell contains a 2*n matrix.

I am not familiar with the different variable types python supports so I am a bit lost. I tried with nested lists but it ended up very messy. Was it a correct approach? Any suggestions to make my life easier?

```
>> whos profiles
  Name          Size              Bytes  Class    Attributes

  profiles      3x2x11            34848  cell     

>> profiles(1, 1, 1)

ans = 

    [2x20 double]
```

Thanx

Comment: have a look at `numpy` and `scipy`. They might be helpful for working with matlab's matrices.

Comment: Well, I installed the wipython pagckage for that reason. In the gui that comes with (spyder) I can import .mat files. This workes for 2D cell arrays and it returned 2 levels nested lists (for the 2 dimensions of the cell). It doesn't work with 3D cells though.

Comment: In what way didn't it work?  It is hard to help you without you showing your python code, showing what it gave you, and explaining that difference between what you got and what you want.

Comment: Thanks. I tried using the import from spyder gui (which I suppose uses scipy.io in some way??). Indeed, by using the loadmat method it worked and it returns a dictionary containing nested lists according to the dimensions of the imported matlab cell array (3D in my case). Exactly what I wanted!